# Why Stack Doesn't Roll Back

Tags: c++, operating-system, stack

We've studied that Stack expands and shrink. But in practice it doesn't happen
Take an example of a stack which expands from addresses 100 to 0 i.e. first variable goes to 100, then next to 99 etc. Now when we write the following code

```
int main()
{
   {
      int i;
      cout<<&i;//100 is displayed on screen
   }
   {
      int j;
      cout<<&j;//99 is displayed on screen
   }
}
```

Now when we declared i, it goes to address 100 and then its scope finishes. Then j is declared in a new scope and now it should have address 100 again because i is finished and stack should roll back but it doesn't, j has address 99. WHY? can you explain??

Comment: By the way, you tagged the question C but you are clearly using a C++ compiler. So I re-tagged with the correct language.

Comment: Get a better compiler that reuses the stack more efficiently.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's probably exactly the same compiler, but building for Release instead of Debug. In debug mode it's quite useful to see value of variables even after they're needed.

Comment: @MSalters: Mm, maybe. I think GCC only started reusing the stack sensibly quite recently, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allocating space on the stack takes some time, albeit very small. One very common optimization that compilers make is to analyze the variables declared within a function and reserve stack space for all of them at the same time at the start of the function.

An even smarter compiler would realize that the lifetimes of the two variables don't overlap, and let them share the same location.

Answer (score 6):

The standard makes no such promise about the the storage of local variables. There is no reason to believe that the order of declaration has any relationship with the order in which they are laid out in memory.

It is entirely at the behest of the compiler how it is done. Indeed, for your program, the compiler could use the same address for both variables. I would expect any decent optimising compiler to do so.

Now, in practice, compilers may well use the sorts of optimisations that you talk about. But how these optimisations are implemented will vary from compiler to compiler. And there's no reason for the simple rule that you describe to apply universally to all functions. The compiler may choose one strategy for one function, and a different strategy for a different function. The compiler may behave differently depending on its options.

Of course, if you are talking about the stack frames associated with function calls, then it is different. Clearly when you make a new function call, a new stack frame is allocated. And then when the function returns, that stack frame is destroyed, and the calling function's stack frame is re-entered. But that's an entirely different matter, and is not what you discuss in the question.

Comment: suppose there are no other processes running and memory is allocated from 100 to 0

Comment: Why should we suppose that? Why would it matter whether or not other processes are running?

Comment: Stack has to roll back.. isn't it?

Comment: It's still up to the compiler to decide how to handle the code and variable layout.  You are not in charge of how it lays out variables.  It could reuse the space; it doesn't.  It might reuse the space if it was optimized and not reuse it if it is not.

Comment: @Ahmed Why? The compiler can do whatever it feels like.

Comment: well my teacher gave me the task to find out an answer so it must not be as simple that it's up to the compiler. There must be a technical argument

Comment: No he can't be :)... He teaches me OPERATING SYSTEMS. Think with respect to gcc compiler

Comment: Or perhaps you misunderstood the question. What I state in my answer is accurate.

Comment: @Ahmed: In reality, the variables will not even be on the stack. It's just a single variable which will fit in a CPU register. It's only because you wrote `&i` that the compiler had to **invent** a stack address, and even then it probably won't **use** that address. One of the challenges of modern computers: trying to observe them alters the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Stack will always expand and roll back in case of function calls, because the execution path is not really predictable and we need to store information about local variables and return address of each running function in the call tree.

The situation here is different, the stack pointer doesn't even move, and the compiler is free to optimize the code and use two different addresses for two small variables, even if this cause a minimal memory waste.